# svn practice for scenario when branches and tags are mixed

Tags: svn, tags, branch

The thing is our application will have non-functional differences in order to support xp and windows 7 respectively, mostly due to the language and .net framework limits. Meanwhile, we surely are going to have different versions. So my current thoughts is to use tag to represent the release versions and branch to indicate the OS platforms. But this seems tedious, like a cross join.

The question is: should i include branch/tag while creating the branch/tag? or just branching/tagging the trunk? I doubt where to go and find v1.0 for xp if i only branch/tag the trunk?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, in the svn world, branches are used for development and tags are used to give alphanumeric names to certain revisions (or just to make them stand out in comparison to the others).

Technically, both are exactly the same. They are folders that were copied from another location within the repository (often trunk, but sometimes other branches as well).

In short, if you just want to mark certain revisions for their specialty (be it a version number or OS), use tags. If you want to so actual development on them, use branches.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i'm aware of the concepts. i was asking about the solution for the scenario of 2 branches based on 2 factors.